# Clear conditional formatting using Advanced Sheet Service in Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to delete conditional formating of a range using below code:

```
var sheet = range.getSheet();
var address = range.getA1Notation();

var conditionalFormatRules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
var conditionalFormatRule = [];
var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
for (let index = 0; index < conditionalFormatRules.length; index++) {
    let ranges = conditionalFormatRules[index].getRanges();
    for (let j = 0; j < ranges.length; j++) {
        if (ranges[j].getA1Notation() == address) {
            conditionalFormatRule.push({
                "deleteConditionalFormatRule": {
                    "index": index,
                    "sheetId": sheetId
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

if (conditionalFormatRule.length > 0) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ssId = spreadsheet.getId();
    var format_req = {
        "requests": conditionalFormatRule
    };
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(format_req, ssId);
}
```

But it fails with the following exception:

```
{ [GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[8].deleteConditionalFormatRule: No conditional format on sheet: 1876237346 at index: 8] name: 'GoogleJsonResponseException', details: { message: 'Invalid requests[8].deleteConditionalFormatRule: No conditional format on sheet: .... at index: 8', code: 400 } }
```

It says there is no conditional formatting at index: 8 but there are 11 conditional format rules for that particular range (confirmed by logging the conditional formatting rules)

I want to delete all the conditional formatting rules for a particular range if there is any better way please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is NO method to delete conditional formatting in a particular range directly. Goole script only supports delete ALL the conditional formatting in one sheet by **clearConditionalFormatRules()**. Accordingly, to achieve your goal, just do the following steps: 
1. Delete All the conditional formatting in the sheet. 
2. Add the conditional rules you wanna preserve.

Don't try to parse the array of getConditionalFormatRules(), there is no useful information in it. It looks like [com.google.apps.maestro.server.beans.trix.impl.ConditionalFormatRuleApiAdapter@1c15adca].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by using [getConditionalFormatRules](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getConditionalFormatRules()), [clearConditionalFormatRules](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearConditionalFormatRules()), and [setConditionalFormatRules](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setConditionalFormatRules(ConditionalFormatRule)) methods of [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) class.

1. Get all conditional formatting rules and store it in a variable
   `existingRules`.
2. Remove the rules from `existingRules`.
3. Concat new rules `newRules` and `existingRules`.
4. Clear all conditional formatting rules.
5. Set all conditional formatting rules `allRules` to the sheet again.

---

```
var existingRules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
     var removedRules = [];
     for (let index = 0; index < existingRules.length; index++) {
     let ranges = conditionalFormatRules[index].getRanges();
    for (let j = 0; j < ranges.length; j++) {
        if (ranges[j].getA1Notation() == address) {
           removedRules.push(existingRules[index]);
         }
       }
    }

    for (var i = removedRules.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        existingRules.splice(removedRules[i], 1);

    var newRules = [] //skipping the logic to create new rules
    var allRules = existingRules.concat(newRules);
    //clear all rules first and then add again
    sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules(); 
    sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(allRules);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update/add new rules to one range, while preserving old rules in the sheet in different ranges, you can achieve that by changing the condition and skipping splicing in your code, like that:

```
var existingRules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
var rulesToKeep = [];
var rangeToUpdate ="A1:B10"
 for (let index = 0; index < existingRules.length; index++) {
 let ranges = conditionalFormatRules[index].getRanges();
for (let j = 0; j < ranges.length; j++) {
    if (ranges[j].getA1Notation() != rangeToUpdate.getA1Notation()) {
       rulesToKeep.push(existingRules[index]);
     }
   }
}
var newRules = [] //skipping the logic to create new rules
var allRules = rulesToKeep.concat(newRules);
//clear all rules first and then add again
sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules(); 
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(allRules);
```

Very important is to get `getA1Notation()` for both ranges for comparison, even if your range string is already in `A1Notation()`